# How to have multiple `if let` with a Rust iterator?

Tags: rust

I have this code:

```
fn main() {
    let mut args = std::env::args();

    if let Some(name) = args.next() {
        if let Some(first) = args.next() {
            println!("One arg provided to {}: {}", name, first);
        }
    }
}
```

Is it possible to have two `if let`s? I tried:

```
fn main() {
    if let Some(name) = args.next() && Some(first) = args.next() {
        println!("one arg provided to {}: {}", name, first);
    }
}
```

and

```
fn main() {
    if let Some(name) = args.next() && let Some(first) = args.next() {
        println!("one arg provided to {}: {}", name, first);
    }
}
```

But this does not work. How to do this?

Comment: Any new way of doing this??

Comment: @cdecompilador [Still in development](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/53667). You can have more information [here](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/2497-if-let-chains.html).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use a “fused” iterator to collect multiple values into a tuple and use `if let` with that:

```
fn main() {
    let mut args = std::env::args().fuse();
    if let (Some(a), Some(b)) = (args.next(), args.next()) {
        println!("{}, {}", a, b);
    }
}
```

([Example on the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=862a33d842f05d4281e0a35b6ddff07e&version=stable&backtrace=0))

`fuse` guarantees that after `next` returns `None` once, every call to `next` will give `None`.